# WSO2 analytics : database already in use

Tags: wso2, h2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to start WSO2 analytics (~/wso2am-analytics-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh start) it doesnt work and I get a "Database already in use" in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

After a some investigations, I've found that there was an other instance of WSO2 analytics running.

It's not supposed to be possible since when you do "~/wso2am-analytics-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh start" and and instance in already running, it should say "Process is already running" after comparing the process running to the PID written in wso2carbon.pid.

The problem is if you use wso2server.sh with an unknown or mistyped arg, it still starts but skipping the PID test :

```
  if [ -e "$CARBON_HOME/wso2carbon.pid" ]; then
    if  ps -p $PID > /dev/null ; then
      echo "Process is already running"
      exit 0
    fi
  fi
```

To correct this, I've added this at the end of the $CMD tests :

```
else
  echo "Command $c unknown"
  exit 1
fi
```

EDIT : I have to say this doesn't work.

1. It prevents "./wso2server.sh start" to start server, for an unknown reason (it doesn't echo anything, it just doesnt start and exit with 1).
2. It prevents options to be passed like "-Dsetup" necessary when u need to recreate H2 demo database.